# What exactly is a rollback?

Tags: support

I can't seem to find any information in the FAQ about rollbacks?  What purpose do they serve for our stack-exchange site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rollback is another word for reverting an edit to a previous version. See [this duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) on Meta Stack Overflow.